# Avoid Getting negative Value on Time Subtraction Laravel php

Tags: php, sql, laravel, timestamp, strtotime

I'm subtracting 2 different times and getting negative values, to explain it further here is my code:

```
        <td>{{date('l',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{date('jS F, Y',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{$date1=date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{$date2=date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logoff))}}</td>
        <td>{{$result=$date2-$date1}}</td>            
        <td>
```

The $result value sometimes goes negative because its somethimes subtracting pm and am. Any ways to avoid this? thanks

Comment: You cannot subtract times like that.

Comment: Any answer? or suggestions?

Comment: `$diff_in_seconds = strtotime($mydate->logoff) - strtotime($mydate->logon);` or use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: You should not do calculations in your view files.